# Cygwin terminal cannot find the installed package

Tags: cygwin

I have install `Cygwin` in `C:\cygwin64` and installed [e2fsprogs](http://www.cygwin.com/packages/summary/e2fsprogs.html) package; but Cygwin terminal still cannot find `e2fsck`:

[image]

**C:\cygwin64\var\log\setup.log:**

```
2021/07/16 16:40:46 Starting cygwin install, version 2.909
2021/07/16 16:40:46 User has backup/restore rights
2021/07/16 16:40:46 Current Directory: C:\cygwin64
2021/07/16 16:40:50 source: network install
2021/07/16 16:40:53 root: C:\cygwin64 system
2021/07/16 16:40:54 Selected local directory: C:\cygwin64
2021/07/16 16:40:55 net: Preconfig
2021/07/16 16:40:57 site: http://cygwin.mirror.constant.com/
2021/07/16 16:40:59 solving: 0 tasks, update: yes, use test packages: no
2021/07/16 16:41:43 solving: 1 tasks, update: no, use test packages: no
2021/07/16 16:41:43 Augmented Transaction List:
2021/07/16 16:41:43    0 install e2fsprogs 1.44.5-1 
2021/07/16 16:41:48 Downloaded C:\cygwin64/http%3a%2f%2fcygwin.mirror.constant.com%2f/x86_64/release/e2fsprogs/e2fsprogs-1.44.5-1.tar.xz
2021/07/16 16:41:48 Extracting from file://C:\cygwin64/http%3a%2f%2fcygwin.mirror.constant.com%2f/x86_64/release/e2fsprogs/e2fsprogs-1.44.5-1.tar.xz
2021/07/16 16:41:48 Changing gid back to original
2021/07/16 16:41:48 running: C:\cygwin64\bin\dash.exe "/etc/postinstall/0p_000_autorebase.dash"
2021/07/16 16:41:51 running: C:\cygwin64\bin\dash.exe "/etc/postinstall/0p_update-info-dir.dash"
2021/07/16 16:41:52 running: C:\cygwin64\bin\dash.exe "/etc/postinstall/zp_man-db-update-index.dash"
2021/07/16 16:41:52 Changing gid to Administrators
2021/07/16 16:41:54 note: Installation Complete
2021/07/16 16:41:54 Ending cygwin install
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I have to use the full path which is:

```
/usr/sbin/e2fsck
```

Comment: Or add `/usr/sbin`  to your PATH. The same applies to **any** executable you want to run....